# inlineformset_factory Saves only First Row data?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, inline-formset, django-2.1

I am working on **inlineformset factory** all work fine but **formset** data stores **only first value.**

i am using **formset.js** file to add rows.

**parent model** data saved but **formset data** stored only **first row information**.

Here is my code

> forms.py

Here is my formset code

```
    SizeChartFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
        TailoringProductsMaster, SizeChart, extra=1,
        fields='__all__',
        form =SizeChartForm,
        can_delete=True,
        widgets={'SizeType': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':"form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12",}),
                 'RequiredFabric': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12",}),
                 },
    )
```

> Views.py

Here is my view code

```
class TailoringProductsMasterCreateView(CreateView):
    model = TailoringProductsMaster
    form_class = TailoringProductsMasterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(TailoringProductsMasterCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['operations_form'] = SizeChartFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        else:
            context['operations_form'] = SizeChartFormSet()

        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        operations_form = SizeChartFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)


        if (form.is_valid() and operations_form.is_valid()):
                return self.form_valid(form, operations_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, operations_form)


    def form_valid(self, form, operations_form):

        self.object = form.save()
        operations_form.instance=self.object
        operations_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())


    def form_invalid(self, form, operations_form):

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(form=form, operations_form=operations_form ))
```

> html page (see this link for home htmle page - http://www.codeshare.io/arY9l6 see this hole html page

```
                                                <tbody>
                                                     {% if operations_form.errors %}
                                {{ operations_form.errors }}
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ operations_form.non_field_erros }}

                            {% for object in operations_form %}
                            {{ object.id }}
                            <tr id="formset">
                                <td class="m-ticker">{{ object.SizeType }}</td>
                                <td>{{ object.RequiredFabric }}</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                                                </tbody>

                                            </table>
{{ operations_form.management_form }}
```

Comment: I can't see the whole of your template, are you sure all of your forms are inside `<form></form>` tags?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/arY9l6  see this hole html page

Answer (score 0):

In your template you are overriding the forms
This you do 2x

```
{% for object in operations_form %}
  {{ object.id }}
  <tr id="formset">
  <td class="m-ticker">{{ object.SizeType }}</td>
  <td>{{ object.RequiredFabric }}</td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and this once

```
{% for gal in operations_form %}
  {{ gal.id }}
  <tr id="formset">
  <td class="m-ticker">{{ gal.SizeType }}</td>
  <td>{{ gal.RequiredFabric }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

But this is not the way to deal with formsets. What you are doing in your template now is basically this (three times):

```
{% for form in formset %}
  {{ form.id }}
  {{ form.SizeType }}
  {{ form.RuiquiredFabric }}    
{% endfor %}
```

This will cause the same forms to be rendered with the exact same html (you only use different variable names, but that doesn't change the rendered html)

That is why only one form(set) is showing up in the post data.

**UPDATE**

html is correct and all data is in the request.POST so it has to do with your form_valid() maybe?

Try:

```
operations = operations_form.save(commit=False) 
for operation in operations: 
    operation.(fill in the field reference) = self.object
    operation.save()
operations.save()
```

Comment: i remove all commented code .but still not working   see link for html code http://www.codeshare.io/arY9l6    there is only one formset

Comment: Can you see all the data you entered in the request.POST?

Comment: yes in request.POST i see all data. but in DB store only first row data

Comment: **error occurs :**    save() prohibited to prevent data loss due to unsaved related object 'TailoringProducts'. on this line         operations.save()

Comment: `def form_valid(self, form, operations_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        operations = operations_form.save(commit=False) 
        for operation in operations: 
         operation.instance = self.object
         operation.save()
        operations.save()`

Comment: Sorry, this is how far my knowledge of formsets goes. Maybe someone else can help you

Comment: same code works with my django 1.11 version but in 2.1 it not

Comment: Have you looked into its documentation? Mean to say, have you checked 1.11 and 2.1 both and the way to use 2.1. Definitely, there will be some usage related issues if  the same works with 1.11. Just check ans let us know. Django 2.1 has different style of defining URL patterns, registering app. So, it's better if you check the usage of both and compare them.

Comment: Yes , i checked documtation , every think is fine , but there is something that i did not get or i missed